# Are subjective & argumentative questions ever allowed on SO?

Tags: feature-request

As far as I have seen, subjective questions are frowned upon at Stack Overflow. Given that

- Google is often overrun with spam and therefore not reliable to answer subjective / comparative queries;
- SO is already a knowledge-based community with a built-in trust (aka reputation) system;

#### Feature Request

I suggest the powers that be implement a system which

- Software-development related subjective and argumentative questions could be made (maybe in a separate area or sister SE site);
- Reputation-whoring is discouraged, maybe doing away entirely with reputation points in such questions.

I know there's a thing called Community Wiki, but it doesn't seem to be intended for this scenario, and common users cannot start one anyway.

Comment: Many people are here because the sites are not drowning in discussion

Comment: @random It could be allowed in a separated (but equal) area.

Comment: Feel free to throw into the fray: http://area51.stackexchange.com/categories/8/technology?tab=progress

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you want to see argumentative questions?  If some asks questions simply for the sake of "stirring the pot", I wouldn't want to be part of their community.  Questions that have merit and value should be able to be phrased without being overtly argumentative.

If you have questions about programming that might be subjective (ie., vague discussion about the merits of Framework A vs FrameWerk 2.0), maybe try asking on [programmers.se](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: merits of Framework A vs 2.0, which IDE to use, best library to something... exactly the kind of subjective questions i'm thinking of.

Comment: @tiagoinu Then we've got you covered (for the most part) on Programmers. Check out the [FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq) for more details.

Comment: Shooting myself in the foot with an off-topic subjective comment: programmers.se's design is the prettier in SE. I wonder whether all designs are made by the same team...

Comment: @tiagoinu That's a topic for http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/